# Converting BitArray to Byte

Tags: c#, byte, bitarray

I have a code that converts `BitArray` values to `byte[]` values. I got the code also from stackoverflow.

The code is working great, I just don't understand one part.

When the codes copies the `BitArray` to `Byte` using `BitArray.CopyTo()` the `byte` reading is in *LSB order*.

Can someone help me understand why the converted byte is in LSB order?

```
strBit (is a string value that consists of 1/0)
byte[] myByte = new byte[50];

List<string> list = Enumerable.Range(0, strBit.Length / 8)
    .Select(i => strBit.Substring(i * 8, 8))
    .ToList();

for (int x = 0; x < list.Count; x++)
{
    BitArray myBitArray = new BitArray(list[x].ToString().Select(c => c == '1').ToArray());
    myBitArray.CopyTo(myByte, x);
}
```

Example Output:

```
  strBit[0] = 10001111  (BitArray)
```

when converted to Byte:

```
  myByte[0] = 11110001 (Byte) (241/F1)
```

Comment: Because you have to choose some encoding and the .NET Framework prefers that one/the sender send this one?

Comment: Where should I check that part? or is it a default for Byte data types in .Net framework? Sorry, I'm new to this

Comment: You kinda have to guesstimate wich Encoding the other side is using. https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/ Sometimes you can get hints or even neogiate wich one you want. My advise is to avoid going down to the binary level and let someone elses code deal with this problem for you. | I treat binary representations like Timezones - just ask the black box that can reliably deal with it and do not try to overthink it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-5wpm-gesOY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because we count bits from the *right* and items from the *left*; for instance for

```
 BitArray myBitArray = new BitArray(new byte[] { 10 });
```

We have for the `byte` `10` (counting from the *right*):

```
 10 = 00001010 (binary)
            ^
            second bit (which is 1)
```

when items of the corresponding array we count from the *left*:

```
 {false, true, false, true, false, false, false, false}
           ^
           corresponding second BitArray item (which is true)
```

That's why if we want to have an array of `byte` back we have to `Reverse` each `byte` representation, e.g. *Linq* solution

```
  using System.Collections;
  using System.Linq;

  ...

  BitArray myBitArray = ...

  byte[] myByte = myBitArray
    .OfType<bool>()
    .Select((value, index) => new { // into chunks of size 8
       value,
       chunk = index / 8 })
    .GroupBy(item => item.chunk, item => item.value)
    .Select(chunk => chunk // Each byte representation
      .Reverse()           // should be reversed   
      .Aggregate(0, (s, bit) => (s << 1) | (bit ? 1 : 0)))
    .Select(item => (byte) item)
    .ToArray();
```